# How to run image classification on multiple images?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have worked through the image classification tutorial on the tensorflow website [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification)

The tutorial explains how the trained model can be run as a predictor on a new image.

Is there a way to run this on a batch/multiple images? The code is as follows:

```
sunflower_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/592px-Red_sunflower.jpg"
sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Red_sunflower', origin=sunflower_url)

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
sunflower_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

print(
"This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
.format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
)
```

Comment: What is stopping you from sending multiple images together?

Comment: stack them in your create a batch line

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to run your prediction on multiple images at the same time.

```
import cv2 (pip install opencv-python)

batch_images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in list_images] 

predictions = model.predict_on_batch(batch_images)
```

list_images is a list with paths to your images you want to predict on for example `["path_img1","path_img2",...]`

predictions is a list of predictions that your model made on the given batch of images and they are in the same order as the images you used as an input.
so `predictions[x]` gives you the predictions for the x'th images of the input batch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses Dataset.from_generator to stream images from disk with a generator function.

```
def read_dir():
  files = os.listdir(source_folder)
  for file_name in files:
    yield keras.utils.load_img(source_folder + file_name, color_mode="rgb")

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
  lambda: read_dir(),
  output_types=(tf.int8),
  output_shapes=([128, 128, 3])
)

model = keras.models.load_model('my-model.keras')
predictions = model.predict(ds.batch(64))
```